# Making a simple image slideshow in Javascript

Tags: javascript, slideshow

I am trying to make an image slideshow using Javascript.I will post the whole code to make it clear.I am making an image slideshow.It should swap the images when the buttons are pressed.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <!--The 6th page in the learning process-->
      <title>
        T6
    </title>

    <style>
        button#prev{
            margin-left:45%;
        }
        button{
            letter-spacing: 3px;
            font-weight: 700;
            }
        #mainImg{
            height:480px;   
            width:640px;    
            margin-left:24%;    
            border:8px outset;  
        }
    </style>
    <script>

    //This pre-loads the images.
    //This creates the image array.
    var imag=[];
    for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    //This makes four new image objects in the imag array.      
    imag[imag.length]=new Image();
    };
    //This provides the image URL.
    imag[0].src="file:///D:/Sites/T6/1.jpg";
    imag[1].src="file:///D:/Sites/T6/2.jpg";
    imag[2].src="file:///D:/Sites/T6/3.jpg";
    imag[3].src="file:///D:/Sites/T6/4.jpg";
    //This creates the variable responsible for change.
    //The variable is global so that both functions can access it.
    var Chng=-1;
    //Chng variable is initialized at -1 so that it complies with the array indexes.
    //This is the function that shows the previous image.
    //It is invoked by the #prev button.
    function PrevFnc(){
        switch(Chng){
            //This makes sure that the variable will loop from 0 to 4.
            //If the Chng variable becomes -1, this statement makes it 3 again.
            case -1:
                Chng=3;
                break;
            default:
                Chng--;
                break;
        //This changes the src of the #mainImg to the src of the current image object.
        document.getElementById("mainImg").src=imag[Chng].src;
        }
    }
    function NextFnc(){
        switch(Chng){
            //This makes sure that the variable will loop from 0 to 4.
            //If the Chng variable becomes 4, this statement makes it 0 again.
            case 4:
                Chng=0;
                break;
            default:
                Chng++;
                break;
        //This changes the src of the #mainImg to the src of the current image object.
        document.getElementById("mainImg").src=imag[Chng].src;
        }
    }
   </script>
   </head>

   <body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <img id="mainImg" src="">
    </div>
    <!--These are for next and previous.-->
    <button id="prev" onclick="PrevFnc()"><==</button>
    <button id="next" onclick="NextFnc()">==></button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The problem is that nothing happens when the buttons are clicked.I also searched another such posts but they contain obvious errors.I don't know what is wrong with this code.
The code is loaded with comments that provide detail.Please tell what am I doing wrong.:-).

Comment: try putting your js code inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> tag first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pointing out to some basic mistakes there are in the code :

***1.*** The you have to keep your javaScript code inside *script* tag

***2.*** Whatever you write inside the **switch** case after default statement won't ever get executed.

That's it!! Your code will now work perfectly.

```
switch(val){
    case 1:
        // do your stuff
        break;

    case 2:
        // do other stuff
        break;

    default :
        // if you do nothing this will do rest
        break;

    //now whatever you do doesn't matter. It won't do anything
}
```

[***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/XLrE3/)

Comment: I accidentally didn't post the script tag in here.It is in the source code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<head>
    <title>Change image on click</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="image_one">
        <img src="1.jpg" id="img_id" height="400px" width="200px">
    </div>

    <button type="button" onclick="myfxn()">Change Image</button>

    <p id="para"></p>
    <script>

        var i = 1;
        function myfxn(){


                i++;

                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = i;

                if(i<=5){
                document.getElementById("img_id").src = i+".jpg";
                }
                else{
                document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = "Click again to start from the beginning.";
                         i = 0;
                }




        }

    </script>
</body>
```